# How To assign a number in a integer variable to a string

Tags: c, string, int, printf

Suppose I Have a int variable `c = 4;`

Now I want a string named tin to contain 4

How do I Do that??

without Using 2 Programs. if I `printf("%s",tin)` it must print 4 what can I do

Comment: Please pick a programming book and read the first chapter

Comment: @Zirkonix how is `ToString()` defined for an integer.

Comment: You don't even need a book.  Google will auto-complete this search for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/sprintf) or [snprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/snprintf).

```
int c = 4;
char tin [Some_Length];
sprintf(tin , "%d", c);
```

Or

```
snprintf(tin , Some_Length, "%d", c);
```

Also, there is no string type in C.

Comment: It might be worth elaborating on reasonable values for `Some_Lenght`.